# How to include NULL value in Stuff function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a Sql view using a table to make the result as a comma separated for each unique id using Stuff function. But in many cases the id has NULL value and the same id in another row is having some general value. At the end, the view displays two row for same id one with NULL and another with comma separated values. I just want one row. How to achieve this? Below is my code for understanding:

```
    CREATE VIEW BM_RLOS_VW_RCO_AUTH
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
A.bpm_referenceno AS ref_no, 

STUFF((SELECT ', '+B.takenby
FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm B 
WHERE A.winame ='RCO' AND A.bpm_referenceno=B.bpm_referenceno FOR XML PATH(''),Type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') takenby
FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm A 
)
```

Comment: Why don't you just filter off null records in the where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `A.winame ='RCO'` filter inside the `STUFF`, which will return `NULL` when it's not `'RCO'` for the outer row, and a not null value when it's `'RCO'`, thus generating 2 different rows for the same `ref_no`.

Try this (filter by `B` instead of `A`):

```
ALTER VIEW BM_RLOS_VW_RCO_AUTH
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        A.bpm_referenceno AS ref_no, 
        STUFF(
            (
                SELECT 
                    ', '+B.takenby
                FROM 
                    BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm B 
                WHERE 
                    B.winame ='RCO' AND 
                    A.bpm_referenceno = B.bpm_referenceno 
                FOR XML 
                    PATH(''),Type
            ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
            ,1,2,'') takenby
    FROM 
        BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm A
```

Comment: Thanks. It works great. But why in some result its showing comma separated value and some is having single value. On what basis its calculating?

Comment: The values you will see are the records that have winame RCO for that bpm_referenceno, since that's the filter inside your stuff select. When you see only 1 value, then it means that just 1 record has RCO.

Comment: Great and Thanks! I have posted one more question. Can you please help in that. Link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288700/how-to-calculate-no-of-days-between-two-datetime-column-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Check ISNULL in your column

```
  CREATE VIEW BM_RLOS_VW_RCO_AUTH
  AS
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT A.bpm_referenceno AS ref_no, 
             STUFF((SELECT ', '+ ISNULL( B.takenby ,'' )
      FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm B 
      WHERE A.winame ='RCO' AND A.bpm_referenceno=B.bpm_referenceno FOR XML 
      PATH(''),Type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') takenby
      FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm A 
    )
```

Comment: @MDKAMRANAzam,Why it is not working.Try It.It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following option.
If you want to show 'NULL' for null value then try below.

```
CREATE VIEW BM_RLOS_VW_RCO_AUTH
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
A.bpm_referenceno AS ref_no, 
STUFF((SELECT ', '+ ISNULL(B.takenby, 'NULL')
FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm B 
WHERE A.winame ='RCO' AND A.bpm_referenceno=B.bpm_referenceno FOR XML PATH(''),Type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') takenby
FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm A
)
```

OR If you want to skip NULL value then try below.

```
CREATE VIEW BM_RLOS_VW_RCO_AUTH
    AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
    A.bpm_referenceno AS ref_no, 
STUFF((SELECT ', '+B.takenby
    FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm B 
    WHERE A.winame ='RCO' AND B.takenby IS NOT NULL AND A.bpm_referenceno=B.bpm_referenceno FOR XML PATH(''),Type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') takenby
    FROM BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm A
    )
```

Comment: Your second option won't even run, I think, because that `B` alias isn't available at that point in the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. you are right. Getting an error "The multi-part identifier "B.takenby" could not be bound. Severity 16"

Comment: Not working. Tried with both the answer again I am getting 2 row for each id, one with null and another with comma separated value.

Comment: I am not getting the error. Issue is like I want only unique row in the end table, but your query displays two row for same id, one with Null and another with comma separated values. I only want one row for each id