# How to calculate no. of days between two datetime column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables, T1 includes start date column and T2 includes end date column. Both the columns have both date and time.

T1 has all the rows unique while T2 can have multiple rows for same id and in all the row the end date column might be different (each row with different date and time).

I want to calculate the difference (no. of days) between End date and the start date while keeping in mind that we have to only pick the last date which is lying in the End date column.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH MaxEndDate AS
(
    SELECT
        T2.PrimaryKey,
        MaxEndDate = MAX(EndDate)
    FROM
        T2
    GROUP BY
        T2.PrimaryKey
)
SELECT
    T1.PrimaryKey,
    T1.StartDate,
    M.MaxEndDate,
    AmountDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.StartDate, M.MaxEndDate)
FROM
    T1
    INNER JOIN MaxEndDate AS M ON T1.PrimaryKey = M.PrimaryKey
```

Comment: works like a charm. But can we make this query in a single view. If yes, then please help me how can we do that. Idea is to I have to use the days difference in another Select query.

Comment: I did that. Thanks again.

Comment: How to exclude weekends in days calculation like Friday & Saturday or Saturday & Sunday? I have to exclude non working days.

Comment: @MDKAMRANAzam doing that calculation is not simple. Create the famous calendar table that has one record per day for every year. Add a column on that table that says if it's a working day or not. Then, join this query with the calendar table with a between and sum all days that are working days.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a temporary table using T2 something like

```
Select Distinct ID
,MAX(ENDDATE) As [ENDDATE]
INTO #TMPTABLE1
```

then you include this into T1

```
Select A.ID
,Startdate
,B.ENDDATE
,Datediff(day,A.STARTDATE,B.ENDDATE) as DAYS
From T1 as A inner join 
#TEMPTABLE1 as B on A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

--------get no of days among multiple dates----------

```
 DECLARE @i INT , @numrows INT , @days INT , @Fdate DATETIME , @Tdate DATETIME;

SET
    @days = 0;
    DECLARE @employee_table TABLE ( idx SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,
    1) ,
    EmpId INT ,
    SinceDate DATETIME ,
    TillDate DATETIME );
    -- populate employee table INSERT @employee_table
        SELECT
            EmpId ,
            SinceDate ,
            TillDate 
        FROM
            T_EmpPosting_PIS 
        WHERE
            EmpId = 18 
            AND OfficeTypeID = 1 
        ORDER BY
            TransDate;
    --SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        @employee_table -- enumerate the table 
    SET
        @i = 1;

SET
    @numrows = ( SELECT
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM
        @employee_table );
    IF @numrows > 0 WHILE ( @i <= ( SELECT
        MAX(idx) 
    FROM
        @employee_table ) ) BEGIN          
SET
@Fdate = ( SELECT
    SinceDate                        
FROM
    @employee_table                        
WHERE
    idx = @i                      );
    IF ( @i = @numrows )             BEGIN                 
SET
    @Tdate = GETDATE();

END;

    ELSE             BEGIN                 
SET
    @Tdate = ( SELECT
        TillDate                                
    FROM
        @employee_table                                
    WHERE
        idx = @i                              );

END;

SET
    @days = ( SELECT
        DATEDIFF(DAY,
        @Fdate,
        @Tdate)                     )   @days;

SET
    @i = @i   1;

END;
    SELECT
        @days;
```